# I have created a put() method for a SortedMap but can't seem to get test code to work

Tags: java, dictionary

I just can't get this to work. Idea is to design a method that adds a Key Value pair to a Map, and although the program compiles correctly, test code of format " tracker.put("17/06/2019", "Jeffrey Burns"); " brings up error message

I've tried changing the method arguments to (String, List).

```
public class OfficeDeliveryTracker

private SortedMap<String, List<String>> deliveryTracker; 

/**
* Constructor for objects of class OfficeDeliveryTracker
*/
public OfficeDeliveryTracker()
{
  this.deliveryTracker = new TreeMap<>();  
}
/**
 * Adds key-value pair to the map
 */
public void addMapEntry(String key, String value)
{
   List<String> list = deliveryTracker.get(key);
   if (list == null) {
     list = new ArrayList<String>();
   }
   list.add(value);
   deliveryTracker.put(key, list);
 }
```

I expect for the test code tracker.put("17/06/2019", "Jeffrey Burns"); to work, but instead get "Error: line 1 - cannot find symbol - method put(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)"

Comment: Ha, yes, the class is 
    public class OfficeDeliveryTracker

I'll edit the code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out below code:

> As you are using `SortedMap<String, List<String>>`  which takes String as key and list of String as value.

You can't use `tracker.put("17/06/2019", "Jeffrey Burns")` as "Jeffrey Burns" is String not List of String

```
public class OfficeDeliveryTracker {
    private SortedMap<String, List<String>> deliveryTracker;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class OfficeDeliveryTracker
     */
    public OfficeDeliveryTracker() {
        this.deliveryTracker = new TreeMap<>();
    }

    /**
     * Adds key-value pair to the map
     */
    public void addMapEntry(String key, String value) {
        List<String> list = deliveryTracker.get(key);
        if (list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        list.add(value);
        deliveryTracker.put(key, list);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OfficeDeliveryTracker tracker = new OfficeDeliveryTracker();
        //tracker.put("17/06/2019", "Jeffrey Burns"); // Error : The method put(String, String) is undefined for the type OfficeDeliveryTracker;
        tracker.addMapEntry("17/06/2019", "Jeffrey Burns");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you suggest a format for test code, in that case?

Comment: I may be not understood  your question properly, but If you are using addMapEntry method, then tracker.addMapEntry("Str1", "Str1");  tracker.addMapEntry("Str2", "Str2")  ....

Comment: `deliveryTracker` != `tracker`, or is it?

Comment: In above code `tracker` is reference of OfficeDeliveryTracker class and `deliveryTracker` is SortedMap

Comment: Ohmigosh, I've spent ages staring at this trying to figure out where I've been going wrong and it's been staring me in the face the whole time. Thanks, Shashwat!